# Shared ViewModel between Fragments with viewPager2

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, viewmodel, android-viewmodel

I have a Fragment0 which contains a ViewPager2 that internally may contain 1 or more child Fragments.

[image]

I have created a SharedViewModel and defined it in the Parent fragment like so:

```
val viewModel by viewModels<SharedViewModel>()
```

I have also added definition for the viewModel in each of the child Fragments.

```
private val sharedViewModel by viewModels<SharedViewModel>(
    ownerProducer = { requireParentFragment() }
)
```

I use the NavigationControl to navigate to Fragment4 from each of these Child Fragments viz. Fragment1, Fragment2 and Fragment3. My question is, how can I share the same view Model with Fragment4 which is not directly a child of the Fragment0. Can I use the same approach to share viewModel with Fragment4 as well?

Or is there a better way to handle such a usecase?

Comment: Try using Dagger hilt for ViewModel injection in fragments.

Comment: Is Fragment4 displayed in the same activity as Fragment0?

Comment: for me, if I initialize viewmodel in fragments inside the viewpager with... ownerProducer = { requireParentFragment() }... I get a crash. It says, the fragment inside the viewpager is not a child fragment, it is directly attached to the activity. I only have one acticity. Does it work for you?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `by viewModels({requireParentFragment()})` only to share viewmodel with parent and child fragment.
It will not work with fragment4.

you can use `by activityViewModels()`.
but it's not good architecture. i suggest you to create separate viewmodel for Fragment4 and share the data with navigation.

find more from here: https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/communicate